# Bypass admin login requirements for Installers (Mac)

Tags: python, macos, command-line, installation

Please forgive any unclear terminology, I'm pretty new to coding.
I'm just getting started with test automation, and am writing a smoke test for a desktop application installer that mounts the dmg, opens the installer.pkg and runs through the dialogs to complete the installation. The script is written in Python 2.7 and uses the ldtp library. 
However, I'm getting stuck when the login requirement dialog pops up. Since the login dialog has no identifier or window name, I'm not able to grab the window and start typing using ldtp. I guess I could try using coordinates to click on the window, but I'd rather just bypass that dialog altogether. 
So, is there some way to temporarily elevate the permissions for the process so the login requirement is bypassed? 
I've tried running the following in terminal, but the login requirement still pops up.

```
os.system('sudo open <filepath>.pkg')
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You're making things hard on yourself, I think. There's a command line utility /usr/sbin/installer you can use to install .pkg and .mpkg files. Run that with root privs and you won't get prompted for a dialog box.

Comment: Thanks, bil. This definitely works for a silent install. I should have specified that I need to be able to step through the GUI to verify it is working correctly (correct options checked, etc.). And I can do that no problem with the other sections of the installer, it's just that the Authorization dialog is proving difficult to focus on and type into. Is there a way to bypass the dialog while still using the GUI? Thanks!